# prove that the minimal $\sigma$-field always exists as a consequence of the fact that intersection of $\sigma$-fields is a $\sigma$-field

Tags: measure-theory

> Interesction of $\sigma$-fields is a $\sigma$-field. Consequently, the minimal $\sigma$-field always exists.

While there are many proofs for the first part of the statement, I don't know how to prove the second part is a consequence of the other?

Roughly, I can understand that if $F_1$ and $F_2$ are two $\sigma$-fields containing $C$, then we can always have a smaller $\sigma$-field containing $C$ until we get the smallest possible one. But, how can I write this more formally, if at all?

Comment: Take the intersection of all of them?

Comment: @Randall OH right! that would be the smallest generating $\sigma$-field!